# Passing a variable from my JS file to my HTML file?

Tags: html, json, node.js, angular

I have this code :

```
var uri = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'
+ '?' + qs.stringify({oauth_token: oauthToken})
```

Trying to use that 'uri' variable (< a href=uri essentially) in one of my angular-src component HTML files.

Is it possible..? Using NodeJS

EDIT: The full code :

```
var oauthToken = "";
var oauthTokenSecret = "";
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
//Step-1 Obtaining a request token
request.post({url : requestTokenUrl, oauth : oauth}, function (e, r, body){

//Parsing the Query String containing the oauth_token and oauth_secret.
var reqData = qs.parse(body);
oauthToken = reqData.oauth_token;
oauthTokenSecret = reqData.oauth_token_secret;

//Step-2 Redirecting the user by creating a link
//and allowing the user to click the link
var uri = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'
+ '?' + qs.stringify({oauth_token: oauthToken})
 res.render('home', {url : uri});
```

I am not using a view engine so I am trying to just forget about the res.render and simply pass the dynamic variable to my HTML file.

Comment: Can you provide a little more code that surrounds the example above?

Comment: I went ahead and added more of the code

Comment: What does your call to `res.render` do? There must be some kind of template, like an EJS file, that is part of your code. Can you please include that too.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using EJS files in Express.

In your EJS file `home.ejs` add something like this:

```
<script>
var authUrl = "<%= url %>";
<script>
```

Then, in the browser you can just use the value of the variable `authUrl`.

What this is doing is taking the EJS variable `url`, that you defined in your `res.render` function call, and placing it, as a string, into the HTML that will be sent to the browser. Then the browser takes that value and loads it into the variable `authUrl`.

Comment: I am actually not using EJS, I simply have HTML files corresponding to my website's pages (Dashboard, profile, login, register, etc)

Comment: in your code you have: `res.render('home', {url : uri});` what are you using, if not EJS? Can you post more of your app setup.  The code before your line that reads `app.get('/', function (req, res) {`